# apply if else mutate function on all columns of a spark dataframe in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

How can one apply an if else mutate function on all columns of a spark dataframe in sparklyr? For example, say I want to convert all values less than 2 in the iris dataframe to 0. Outside of sparklyr, there are a number of ways of doing this, but with sparklyr this seems a bit more complex. I tried one such way using the following custom function:

```
iris_sdf <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
iris_num_sdf <- iris_sdf %>% select(-Species)

recode_val <- function(x) ifelse(x < 2, 0, x)

iris_num_sdf %>% mutate_all(funs(recode_val))
```

But got an error `This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7 Error : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:`

I tried the following using `spark_apply` but got nonsensical results.

```
iris_num_sdf %>% 
  spark_apply(recode_val, context = {colName <- colnames(iris_num_sdf)})
```

I also tried this below, which seems to do the trick, but am hoping for something more elegant.

```
convert_x <- function(col){
  col <- sym(col)
  iris_num_sdf %>% mutate({{col}} := ifelse({{col}} < 2, 0, {{col}})) %>% select({{col}})
}

col_list <- colnames(iris_num_sdf)
out <- lapply(col_list, convert_x)

do.call(sdf_bind_cols, out)
```

Comment: Can you use `purrr` functions like `map_df` etc in sparklyr ?

Comment: @RonakShah yes `purrr` functions are available

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach -

```
library(dplyr)

convert_x <- function(col){
  iris_num_sdf %>% transmute({{col}} := ifelse(.data[[col]] < 2, 0,.data[[col]]))
}

col_list <- colnames(iris_num_sdf)
result <- purrr::map_dfc(col_list, convert_x)
```

---

A base R option -

```
recode_val <- function(x) ifelse(x < 2, 0, x)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(iris_num_sdf, recode_val))
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently only a handful of purrr functions work and map_dfc isnt one of them.

Comment: I don't know which ones work and which ones does not but using `result <- purrr::map(col_list, convert_x) %>% bind_cols()` works the same way if you can use that.

Comment: Oddly still not working, i know map works with sparklyr but its unclear to me under what conditions.

Comment: I updated the answer with a base R option. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, base r approaches dont work with sparklyr.